# php Выбрать цифры исключая между ними остальные символы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как получить цифры при этом не включая другие символы вот в таком примере:

`<a href="/test?r=1" class="dt_item">Текст <em class="dt_counter">23<span class="delitel"> </span>289</em></a>`

Нужно получить число 23289 не включая `<span class="delitel"> </span>`.

`(?<=Текст\s\<em\sclass=\"dt_counter\"\>)\d*\D*\d*(?=<\/em>)` - такое выражение дает такой результат:
`23<span class="delitel"> </span>289`

и вот что-то не сделать так, чтобы в середине вырезались ненужные символы.

Answer (score 1):

Из такого примера проще сначала просто удалить все лишние тэги, а в оставшейся строке удалить все нечисловое

```
$str = '<a href="/test?r=1" class="dt_item">Текст <em class="dt_counter">23<span class="delitel"> </span>289</em></a>';

$result = preg_replace("/\D/", "", strip_tags($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<a href="/test?r=1" class="dt_item">Текст
      <em class="dt_counter">23<span class="delitel"> </span>289</em></a>';

echo preg_replace('~[^<]?(\d+)?[^>]*~', '$1', $string);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Такой результат тоже могу получить, но интересовала возможность одной регуляркой это сделать без дополнительных преобразований.

Comment: @user, обновил ответ, думаю решает вашу проблему.